# spring boot maven plugin doesnt prepend script

Tags: spring, spring-boot, executable, bamboo

I'm using spring boot 1.3.1, Java1.8 and maven 3.3.3.
In the maven pom.xml:
`<plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>

     <configuration>
         <executable>true</executable>
         <layout>ZIP</layout>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <goals>
               <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
       </executions>
  </plugin>`

When I run the mvn clean install on my PC and another Linux VM everything is working fine. But after i submit the changes and Bamboo runs the Maven build with the same parameters for some reason it doesn't prepend shell script.
What am I missing? Is there some environment variable that can force it?

Comment: have you tried running mvn clean install on-your-fat.jar on this remote linux vm? I don't think issue is related to bamboo. Bambo is just executing the local system installed maven. Check maven versions on both your local and this remote vm. Make sure they match or are at least v3.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in building RPM after maven build that removed the script.
The solution was to add to rpm spec the following line:
%define __jar_repack %{nil}